# Official USD exchange rate alike the ECB for EUR

Tags: currency

I am looking for one official API for USD exchange rate however the only answers I found are about using 3rd party APIs.

For EUR there is a public API served by the European Central Bank with the official rates, this is pretty good.

For MXN there is a public API served by Bank of Mexico, a bit tricky by the way.

However, I was unable to find the equivalent API served by the Federal Reserve.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be ok to have an xml file?
https://www.newyorkfed.org/xml/fx.html

Comment: XML is OK if it provides the daily exchange updated and it can be consumed by an app to automate the exchange calculation. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the daily rate and the way to consume it by an application from the service you referred.